# Angular accessing child object in dictionary

Tags: angular

I've got the following data structure for my generic filtering:

```
 export interface bavparam {
  SearchBody: any;
  Op: number;
  Tp: number;
}

export interface QueryParams {
  IdUser: number;
  StartRow?: number;
  MaxRows?: number;
  LastCnt?: number;
  SortOrder: string;
  Params: Record<string, bavparam>;
}
```

I'm trying to get the data in:

```
 public filter(filters: any) {
    let t = this;

    t.qparams.Params = {};

    console.info(filters);

    t.qparams.IdUser = this.bavservice.CurrentUser.IdUser;

    t.qparams.Params["OwnerLabel"].SearchBody = filters["OwnerLabel"];
    t.qparams.Params["OwnerLabel"].Tp = 1;
    t.qparams.Params["OwnerLabel"].Op = 1;
```

And I got exception to the console:

```
ERROR TypeError: can't access property "SearchBody", t.qparams.Params.OwnerLabel is undefined
```

I'm confused, because before the class QueryParams was flat having the following definition:

```
Params: Record<string, any>;
```

and I've been able to assign the value in the following way:

```
t.qparams.Params["OwnerLabel"] = filters["OwnerLabel"];
```

Each time, both sides are of type Any, so nothing has changed. Any clue what might has happened?

Comment: `t.qparams.Params["OwnerLabel"]` is not initialized, hence the error. You could `t.qparams.Params["OwnerLabel"] = {}` before `t.qparams.Params["OwnerLabel"].SearchBody = filters["OwnerLabel"];`

Comment: I recommend you not to assign `this` to variables, it will make your code harder to read.